# Emacs Windows10 ragged font

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, fonts

I'm having issues with ragged or cutoff fonts in emacs with windows10.
It's especially noticeable when looking at the bullets in org-mode bullets which seem pixelated and off center. Specs:

- Display 24" 1920x1080
- scaling: 100%
- Let windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry (ON/OFF does not make a difference).

Please help

[image]

Comment: Can you add more information about your setup, like your operating system, fonts and your config. From what I can see, `org` doesn't use pretty bullets by default, so you've customized at least that.

Comment: What does this have to do with Org mode? Do you not see the same problem elsewhere in Emacs? Do you see the problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? (If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.) Please narrow the problem description to only those things that are necessary (e.g., not tag `org-mode`, probably). Thx.